# Automatically set as expired the column named STATUS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this plan to set the column `status` as "Expired" when there's no uploaded file in column `proof_of_payment` within the set date in column `date_expiration`. (I need this function to expire the order.)

How to make it possible? Can I create condition in sql or manipulate it in php codes?

LIKE FOR AN EXAMPLE: [image]

Comment: 1. Either set up a cron using application code (php) to run at midnight, and update status accordingly
2. Or, create MySQL events again running every day on midnight
I would prefer the method 1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya All due respect. But my question is really specific based on the things I want to do and I have my examples to make it more specific. But thankyou for ur feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok you should first enable event_scheduler using your mysql command line:SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
now lets create your schedule : 
    -you want to update a column if the condition of comparing two other columns are met.i guess this syntax will handle the problem:

```
    CREATE EVENT test_event_04 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO UPDATE table_name SET STATUS='expired' WHERE CURDATE()>date_expiration AND proof_of_payment IS NULL
```

just remember to change table_name to your real table name 
the schedule will run every day once created (EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )

Comment: check this link it may also help you   https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: theres an error. I just turn on event and add events and paste all codes above.

Comment: I also pasted it in sql. But led to error. Im not so good in sql please help

Comment: did you change the your_table_name value to your real table name?

Comment: @faramarz yes I did. Thankyou for your concern, instead of telling people should be like this or should be like that. Thankyou for understanding that everyone starts with a little knowledge about sql. And dont be like someone who burst out their stress through comments or any online platform.

Comment: tnx bro . ill update my answer . im changing the syntax  , this one will probably work for you

Comment: @faramarz okay thankyouu im waiting

Comment: @faramarz thankyou for not being so affected in just a small thing. Anyway, im just talking to you and not to anyone else. So you have a right to say all things you want.

Comment: ok now try it . i guess this one will work . you could set EVERY 1 DAY to EVERY 1 MINUTE to test the result

Comment: @faramarz it worked for me thankyou so much. Now i will use this code as basis and a piece to build somemore of these. Thankyou for giving example like this for me to understand how events works.

Comment: you're welcome :)